# What is the ideal $\sum_{i \in I} \mathfrak{a}_i$?

Tags: commutative-algebra, ideals

I encountered the ideal $\sum_{i \in I} \mathfrak{a}_i$, where the $\mathfrak{a}_i$'s are ideals of an entire ring. However, no explanation was given about this ideal.
Is it the ideal $\lbrace \sum_{i \in I} a_i \mid a_i \in \mathfrak{a}_i \rbrace$?
Is it possible to express this ideal as the ideal generated by some set, *i.e.* the intersection of all ideals containing some set?

Comment: I think elements of that ideal are fintie sums of elements from ideal a_i.

Comment: Exact duplicate of  [Infinite sum of ideals](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/782644/infinite-sum-of-ideals)

Answer (score 2):

The sum of a set of ideals is simply the smallest ideal containing all elements in each of the ideals. If your set is finite then you have
$$
I_1+I_2+...+I_n = \{r_1+r_2+...+r_n\mid r_i \in I_i\}
$$
And if you are considering the sum of an infinite set of ideals, elements are simply sums of elements from any *finite* subset of the ideals. I.e. if you have a set of ideals indexed by the natural numbers then:
$$
\sum_{i \in \mathbb{N}}I_i = \{r_1+r_2+...+r_n\mid r_i \in I_i\, n \in \mathbb{N}\}
$$
In terms of generating set, it's hard to say in general, but you certainly have that the sum of a set of ideals is generated by the union of the generators of each ideal in the sum.

Answer (score 0):

It is given by $\sum_{i\in I}\mathfrak{a}_i=\{\sum_{i\in I} a_i\mid \textrm{all but finitely many }a_i=0\}$ as stated in the comments.